# Is it possible to have global cross references on a quarto website?

Tags: quarto

Im trying to build a quarto website which consists of several QMD files.

Is it possible to have cross references between different QMD files, so that if the "link" is clicked, it takes you to an object which is located in another tab on the website?

Im using the RStudio environment.

I could only find documentation how to do it on the same website tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reference for instance a section in another blog article (blog01.qmd), that have been labelled `## Example section {#sec-example-section}`, you can do the following:

```
[Link](blog01.qmd#sec-example-section)
```

Comment: I am confused by this answer.  All blog posts in  a quarto blog are index.qmd.  How could we reference that?

Comment: Usually, you have several qmd files with different names that make up your blog/website.  You try to rename your index.qmd files to unique names and then call them in your YML file by their names, making sure that they are included in your blog. That way you should also be able to reference them like Julian has described.